# How to read XML File by using the LUHN Formula?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, luhn

I already have the algorithm for the LUHN Formula and my XML file. But I need to implement the data inside the XML file for the LUHN Formula.

Example:
The 123-4567-891 Credit card number is stolen. And the LUHN Formula will read it then prints it for the user.

Comment: The given example of credit card number is inside the XML file.

Comment: so you just want to get this number from `XML` file and check it with your algorithm? please post an example of `XML` file

Comment: The xml file is coded at Eclipse.

Comment: to understand how to parse XML file it's format is needed